# Can I get more overrun despite single-speed machine?

Tags: ice-cream

I love making my own ice cream, and have been doing so with a frozen bowl machine for years. I love my machine and the outcome. But over time, I discovered that I still frequently buy cheap supermarket ice cream just because I enjoy the variety of textures that frozen desserts can have. While my machine is very good at making dense ice cream as in parlors, it cannot get the foamy texture found in a tub of heart brand ice cream.

I know that the default answer to "more overrun" is "increase the churning speed". But I have a dedicated machine, not a stand mixer attachment, and the machine does not allow me to regulate the speed. I don't want to purchase a second machine (or an attachment), as I don't have the space for such extravagance.

Are there any tricks to try to get high overrun at home? Even if they are gimmicky/high effort, I would like to hear them and try them out.

I simply wrote "ice cream" throughout the question, but I'm actually interested in a wide variety of ice cream and frozen masses, including frozen yogurt, sorbet, etc. It is fine if you have an answer which is applicable to only one of those - and even better if you have a general suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

For dairy based frozen dessert try incorporating more air prior to adding the mixture to your machine. Remember cold is your friend, freeze a mixing bowl then using a mixer, whisk or stick blender beat the mixture like you are making whipped cream. You should get additional volume, then churn as usual.

I’m not sure if this would work, but you may be able to whip additional air into the mixture after it’s finished freezing. You would need to work quickly, with very cold implements that could handle the resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change the overrun is by using a different style of dasher. Commercial ice cream machines sometimes have separate dashers for gelato where the blades are angled differently to add less air, making gelato more dense than ice cream.

Home machines don't often have more than one type of dasher but you might check with your machine's manufacturer to see if they have something. I suppose it might also be possible to modify an existing dasher somehow to incorporate more or less air.